# risk of ruin in coin flip game against an infinite bank

Tags: probability, gambling

Mark and Alice agree to play the following game: they will flip a fair coin, with the winner receiving even money, and will play this game over and over until one side is wiped out. Mark has a finite bankroll of $n$ units. Alice has an *infinite* bankroll and can never be ruined.

Given enough time, will Mark get ruined? When do we expect Mark will be ruined?

EDIT: I adapted this from the finite version, where Alice has only $m$ units. There it's easy to see that a wipeout sequence has probability at least $\frac{1}{2}^{m+n}$. The law of large numbers assures us that as the number of flips approaches infinity we will get close to the expectation of this wipeout sequence. However, this argument only works because we can get a finite bound on the total bankroll (namely, $m+n$). In the case where Alice's bankroll is infinite things are less clear because there's no finite bound on Mark's bankroll either, since he can win coins from Alice. My intuition is that Mark will get ruined eventually, but I don't know how to prove it, nor do I have any idea when we'd expect that ruin to occur.

Comment: Hello, and welcome. What are *your* thoughts?  What have you tried? What exactly is giving you trouble? You receive better help on this site when people see what you have done to help yourself and what parts you really need help with.

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin

Comment: Thanks @Graham, I've updated the question.

Comment: You could take a look at these slides, from page 3 till 17: http://www.mysmu.edu/faculty/yktse/NAM/NAM_S5.pdf.

Take the iid variables $(X_i)$ to be variables taking values in $0$ and $2$, each equally likely.

Comment: My above comment is probably slightly misleading. I think looking at general ruin theory might do more harm than good.

Comment: 3 years later and nobody answered properly. Funny. Seem pretty fundamental stuff here, and that incomprehensible PDF should not be needed, under the philosophy of: `"if you understand it, you can explain it."`